# How can I use a regular expression to validate month input?

Tags: regex, perl

I am setting up this example Perl snippet to validate for months in a date:

Some scenarios I want to accept are:

MM
M

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern;
my $month = "(0[1-9]|1[012])";
my $day = "(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])";

system("cls");

do {

    print "Enter in a month: ";
    chomp($pattern = <STDIN>);

    # We only want to print if the pattern matches
    print "Pattern matches\n" if ($pattern =~ /$month/);


} while ($pattern ne "Q");
```

When I run this, it correctly filters from 01-12 but when I change the regex to:

```
$month = "(0?[1-9]|1[012])";
```

then the regex allows 13, 14, etc... what gives?

Comment: (0?[1-0]|1[012]), Invalid [] range "1-0" in regex. typo?

Comment: I agree with Greg Hewgill's answer but the reason you aren't getting what you want is because your regex is missing metacharacters to tell the regex to match the beginning and end of your string (i.e. ^ and $).  As it stands it's matching any part of your string.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you really like to use regex, you need to put ^ and $, like

`"^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$"`

it will not match 13, 14 ....

Comment: pattern match or search problem.

Comment: Note that this would match both `01` and `1`. Might not be obvious for some of us who just copy and paste from SO...

Comment: @DanGordon is right. You can change the regex to ^(0[1-9]|1[012])$ and that would fix the issue.

Comment: I would just remove the `?` after `0` because validating `1991-7` does not seem very "standard".

Comment: don't like this solution

Answer (score 22):

You shouldn't use a regular expression to do numeric range validation. The regular expression you want is:

```
/^(\d+)$/
```

Then,

```
if ($1 >= 1 && $1 <= 12) {
    # valid month
}
```

This is much easier to read than any regular expression to validate a numeric range.

As an aside, Perl evaluates regular expressions by *searching* within the target for a matching expression. So:

```
/(0[1-9]|1[012])/
```

searches for a 0 followed by 1 to 9, or a 1 followed by 0, 1, or 2. This would match "202" for example, and many other numbers. On the other hand:

```
/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/
```

searches for an optional 0 1 to 9, or a 1 followed by 0, 1, or 2. So "13" matches here because it contains a 1, matching the first half of the regex. To make your regular expressions work as you expect,

```
/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$/
```

The `^` and `$` anchor the search to the start and end of the string, respectively.

Comment: `/(0[1-9]|1[012])/` would not match "202", it would match the 02 part of "2**02**", but that is quite differant.

Comment: +1: Regular expressions for simple numerical validation is overkill.

Comment: @Paul: Depends on what you mean by "match".  In this case, using the regular expression to *match* against `202` (i.e. `$pattern =~ m/$month/`, noting the meaning of the `m` prefix) would return a true value, and for the code given that is precisely what we don't want.  However, it would only *capture* the `02` part with the parens.  So if you use match to mean capture, then no, it would not.

Answer (score 5):

To give you hint - month number "120" also matches in your version :-)

Change:

```
my $month = "(0[1-9]|1[012])";
```

to

```
my $month = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])$/;
```

and then play more with it

Answer (score 3):

(0[1-9]|1[012])

the parens are so you can use this inside another block, for example if matching for an entire yyyy-MM-dd date format

source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regular expressions.

Perl has the ability to automatically evaluate as a number or a string based on context.  01-09 will evaluate to 1-9 in the numeric context.  So, you can simply check for a value:

```
print "Enter in a month: ";
chomp($pattern = <STDIN>);
# We only want to print if the pattern matches
print "Pattern matches\n" if ($pattern < 13 && $pattern > 0);
```

Comment: And, after you've checked the range, you can printf it with "%02d" if you need the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

`"^(1[012]|0?[1-9])$"`
would be better because regular expression is assessed first one first. Let's say you want to match '12' and you write `"^(0?[1-9]|1[012])$"`, then '1' will be picked because `0?[1-9]` is taken first.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way

```
while(1){
    print "Enter in a month: ";
    $pattern = <STDIN>;
    chomp($pattern);
    if ($pattern =~ /^(Q|q)$/ ){last;}
    if ($pattern =~ /^[0-9]$/ || $pattern =~ /^[0-9][12]$/ ) {
        print "Pattern matches\n";
    }else{
        print "try again\n";
    }
}
```

output

```
$ perl perl.pl
Enter in a month: 01
Pattern matches
Enter in a month: 000
try again
Enter in a month: 12
Pattern matches
Enter in a month: 00
try again
Enter in a month: 02
Pattern matches
Enter in a month: 13
try again
Enter in a month:
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly, 41, 42, 51, 52, etc all say "Pattern matches".

Answer (score 0):

To test `month` / `year` :

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/([2-9][0-9)]{3})$
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[^d>12|d<0] OR ^[d>12|d<0]
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a short explanation as to how/why this regex works for clarification.