# regular expression for date format in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for date format: mm/yyyy in Javascript.

I try by the following.

```
var reDate = /^(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})$/;
```

But not working.
I think the problem is in /

Comment: That's not _regex_, that is a **String**. Use `var reDate = /^(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/;`

Comment: You need a RegExp object, `var rgx = new RegExp(reDate);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use forward slash in regex, it need to be escaped, because it is also used as delimiter.

```
/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/
           ^^
```

---

The above regex will also match any two digits, ex. 00, 99.
Use following regex to match digits only from 1-12.

Credits to [How can I use a regular expression to validate month input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137959/2025923)

```
^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/[0-9]{4}$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/oD6jV6/1)

Comment: Aso matches "0/2015/" `/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/.test("0/2011");`