# Two writing methods from 1 to 12 can be written separately or multiple months, but the middle needs to be separated by a comma and cannot be repeated

Tags: javascript

Regular verification of input pattern can be written individually or 1, 2, 3, 5, 4 from January to December, but cannot be repeated

```
 <input cdkTrapFocus [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true" type="address" matInput
         [(ngModel)]="Time.month" name="month" #month=ngModel
          pattern="^([1-9]|1[0-2])$|^(([1-9]|1[0-2])+(,[1-9]|,1[0-2])*)?$|^[*]*$">
```

I can validate duplicates but I don't know how to merge them on top

```
/\b(\d+)\b.*?,\1\b/.test(event)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, ***noting input and expected output***, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

`[1-9]` matches *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9*

`1[012]` matches *10, 11, 12*

```js
const regex = new RegExp('^([1-9]|1[012])$');

// true.
console.log(regex.test("1")); // true
console.log(regex.test("2")); // true
console.log(regex.test("3")); // true
console.log(regex.test("4")); // true
console.log(regex.test("5")); // true
console.log(regex.test("6")); // true
console.log(regex.test("7")); // true
console.log(regex.test("8")); // true
console.log(regex.test("9")); // true
console.log(regex.test("10")); // true
console.log(regex.test("11")); // true
console.log(regex.test("12")); // true

// false.
console.log(regex.test("123")); // false
console.log(regex.test("111")); // false
console.log(regex.test("01")); // false
console.log(regex.test("13")); // false
```

**REF**: [How can I use a regular expression to validate month input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137929/how-can-i-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-month-input)

#### Addendum

*[Edit]*

You could validate the input on form submission if it has valid months and that the month numbers are not repeated.

```js
const hasValidMonths = input => {
    const regex = new RegExp('^([1-9]|1[012])$');

    return input
        .trim()
        .split(",")
        .every(num => regex.test(num.trim()));
};

const hasUniqueMonths = input => {
    const months = input.trim().split(",").map(m => m.trim());
    return (new Set(months)).size === months.length;
};

let input = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6";

// true.
console.log(hasValidMonths(input) && hasUniqueMonths(input)); // true

// false.
input = "1, 2, 3, 4, 123, 3";
console.log(hasValidMonths(input) && hasUniqueMonths(input)); // false
```

#### Demo

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);

  app.directive('valid.months', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.valid_months = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          // alert(viewValue)
          if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
            // consider empty models to be valid
            return true;
          }

          const regex = new RegExp('^([1-9]|1[012])$');

          return viewValue
            .trim()
            .split(',')
            .every((num) => regex.test(num.trim()));
        };
      },
    };
  });

  app.directive('unique.months', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$validators.unique_months = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
            // consider empty models to be valid
            return true;
          }

          const months = viewValue
            .trim()
            .split(',')
            .map((m) => m.trim());
          return new Set(months).size === months.length;
        };
      },
    };
  });
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-forms-async-validation-production</title>


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>



</head>

<body ng-app="form-example1">
  <form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    <div>
      <label>
    Months:
    <input type="text" ng-model="size" name="size" valid.months unique.months />{{size}}</label><br />
      <span ng-show="form.size.$error.valid_months">The month(s) list format is invalid!. Allowed digits include: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12. Correct format: 1, 2, 3, 5</span>
      <br />
      <span ng-show="form.size.$error.unique_months">The month(s) list specified contains duplicates!. Correct format: 1, 2, 3, 5</span>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Need to write 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and cannot be repeated

Comment: @123KsL , `const regex = new RegExp('^([1-5])$');`

Comment: I may need multiple months so there will be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and it cannot be repeated

Comment: @KsL , check my *Addendum* section in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know if there is a regular expression that directly satisfies all the conditions

Comment: @KsL , none that I can think of. Sorry! 